# Find duplicate content and consolidate in groovy

Tags: groovy, duplicates, text-files

I want to edit a file automatically with groovy.

For example, i have the following textfile:
(First line is only for your understanding)

```
branch ID        item ID      -       -     weight  piece  ---    ---    ---
178568305        108350       0       0       0      -1    215    215    012 
178568305        102190       0       0       0      -1     74     74    012 
178568305        102120       0       0       0      -8     35     35    012 
178568305        102190       0       0       0      -6     74     74    012 
178568305        102190       0       0       0      -6     74     74    012
178587626        108280       0       0       0      -3    189    189    012 
178587626        159550       0       0       0      -1    499    499    012 
178587626        107740       0       0       0      -4    229    229    012 
178587626        105330       0       0     -10       0    626    626    012 
178587626        102190       0       0       0      -6     74     74    012
```

In column 1 i have a brach ID
In column 2 i have a item ID
In column 5 i have a weight, for example in gram
In column 6 i have a number of pieces
Column 3, 4, 7, 8 and 9 are not important

In branch ID:
From line 1 to 5 and 6 and from 6 to 10 i have two different branchs IDs

In item ID:
In line 2, 4 and 5 i have the same item ID always to the same branche ID.

Now, what i want is to consolidate the the item ID 102190 with branch ID 178568305 to one line.
But the piece or weight have to count in sum in these one line.
But attention: In Line 10 i have the same item ID like in Line 2 or 4, but i have a another branch ID. It is not allowed to consolidate the weight/piece from line 10 with 2, 4 and 5!

For Example:

```
branch ID        item ID      -       -     weight  piece  ---    ---    ---
178568305        108350       0       0       0      -1    215    215    012 
178568305        102120       0       0       0      -8     35     35    012 
178568305        102190       0       0       0     -13     74     74    012
178587626        108280       0       0       0      -3    189    189    012 
178587626        159550       0       0       0      -1    499    499    012 
178587626        107740       0       0       0      -4    229    229    012 
178587626        105330       0       0     -10       0    626    626    012 
178587626        102190       0       0       0      -6     74     74    012
```

My input text file is only separated with spaces. My output textfile must be exact the same.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to create this in a groovy script.
Can anyone help? Tutorials are helpful too. I have no idea for the logical script expiration.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to group the data by `branchId` and `itemId`, here is a working code for you:

```
def input = new File("input.txt")

def output = new File("output.txt")


PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(output)

Map<String, String[]> result = [:]

input.eachLine { currentLine, lineNumber ->

    def array = currentLine.split("  +");

    String rowId = array[0] + "_" + array[1];

    if(lineNumber == 1 ){

        result.put(rowId, array)

    }else {



        String[] rowValues = array;

        if(null != result.get(rowId)){

            String[] existingValues = result.get(rowId);

            for(int i = 0; i < existingValues.length; ++i){

                try{

                    existingValues[i] = String.valueOf( rowValues[i].toInteger() + existingValues[i].toInteger())

                }catch (NumberFormatException ex){

                    print(ex)

                }

            }


        }else{

            result.put(rowId, rowValues)

        }

        println(array)

    }


}

int maxColumnWidth = 14;

result.each { key, value ->


    for(int i = 0; i < value.length; ++i){

        if(i == 0){

            printWriter.print(value[i])

        }else{

            String v = value[i];

            while(v.length() < maxColumnWidth){

                v = " " + v;

            }

            printWriter.print(v)

        }


    }

    printWriter.println()



}

printWriter.close()
```

Sample Input:

```
branch ID        item ID      -       -     weight  piece  ---    ---    ---
178568305        108350       0       0       0      -1    215    215    012
178568305        102190       0       0       0      -1     74     74    012
178568305        102120       0       0       0      -8     35     35    012
178568305        102190       0       0       0      -6     74     74    012
178568305        102190       0       0       0      -6     74     74    012
178587626        108280       0       0       0      -3    189    189    012
178587626        159550       0       0       0      -1    499    499    012
178587626        107740       0       0       0      -4    229    229    012
178587626        105330       0       0     -10       0    626    626    012
178587626        102190       0       0       0      -6     74     74    012
```

Output:

```
branch ID       item ID             -             -        weight         piece           ---           ---           ---
178568305        108350             0             0             0            -1           215           215           012
535704915        306570             0             0             0           -13           222           222            36
178568305        102120             0             0             0            -8            35            35           012
178587626        108280             0             0             0            -3           189           189           012
178587626        159550             0             0             0            -1           499           499           012
178587626        107740             0             0             0            -4           229           229           012
178587626        105330             0             0           -10             0           626           626           012
178587626        102190             0             0             0            -6            74            74           012
```

Comment: Wow, works great. Thanks a lot. The only thing is, the Spaces between the first and second line are different. Every "tab" it is one space less between last and next.

Comment: Input:
`178568305        102190       0       0       0      -1     74     74    012 
178568305        102190       0       0       0      -6     74     74    012 
178568305        102190       0       0       0      -6     74     74    012
178587626        108280       0       0       0      -3    189    189    012` output: `178568305        102190       0       0       0      -1     74     74    012 
357136610        204380        0        0        0        -12        148        148        24
178587626        108280        0        0        0        -3        189        189        012`

Comment: Nice. But i'm sorry. The code still have bugs. If you try my first example with 10 lines, the output must be my second example. But if i try it with your code, i get another numbers in the first cell, and the calculation from pieces ist not right (must be 19, not 6).